# Issue with simplesamlphp integration with drupal 9.5.11

Tags: drupal, simplesamlphp

when I integrated simplesamplphp 2.0.6 with drupal 9.5.11 website went down and getting below error
"This page isn’t working"

I have installed simpleamplephp and integrated with wso2 it is working fine. but when I try to integrate simplesamlphp with drupal using simplesaml_auth I'm having issue.
in my settings.php i have given the path to simplesamlphp as below
$settings['simplesamlphp_dir'] = DRUPAL_ROOT.'/../simplesamlphp';
after that my website is going down.
I am using below mentioned vesrons of the softwares
*) Drupal 9.5.11
*) simplesamlphp 2.0.6
*) externalauth 2.0.3
*) simplesaml_auth 3.0.3 or 4.0.0 (both tried)
Is there any version conflicts? if any then please help me to get all the compatible versions to run this perfectly